# Last seen information in Tigase

Tags: xmpp, user-presence, tigase

Tigase shows last seen information which indicates that when this person was last seen by the server. If it is not set than server set it to

```
    protected static final long INITIAL_LAST_SEEN_VAL = 1000l;
```

Can anyone please let me know how tigase server keep tracks of this last seen information.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tigase sets lastSeen field in roster element to current time each time it receives a presence notification from this contact.
Line 1328 in file: tigase.xmpp.impl.Presence:

```
if ((rel != null) && (rel instanceof RosterElement)) {
  ((RosterElement) rel).setLastSeen(System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```